# Can I put NSLog in my model class's implementation ?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, nslog

Can I add NSLog in my model class's implementation. So when I call that method where I have inserted NSLog , from the controller , I should get the strings from that NSLog on my console.

Can I do that ? I tried doing it in my code but I am not sure if it should work or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put NSLog wherever you like. It's a macro.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used anywhere, without a doubt.

> NSLog() is an extended printf() for Objective-C.Its is a Foundation
>   function, accepting a constant NSString as format, having extended
>   format specifier set.
>   It also prints the process name and date before it prints the actual format and writes to sdterr.

Answer (score 0):

You could. But its unnecessary to have a method just for NSLog.

```
-(void)print:(NSString * )text{
  NSLog("%@", text);
}
```

Comment: No the method is not just for NSLog , but it has its own respective functionality . I am asking if I can use NSLog here to print the values of my objects which are initialised, and the elements of my NSMutableArray property.

Comment: User underscore to print the properties of your class. NSLOG("%@",_myString) or NSLog("%@", [NSDictionary description])